# Save emails based on keywords in email text

Tags: vba, outlook

I want my emails saved to different folders on my hard drive based on what the email is about. Some emails should be saved in two or more folders.

The designated hard drive folders are created as they should, and files are saved with the right filenames, but all emails are saved in all folders.

If there is only one keyword from one 'category' present in the mail body. It seems like the script somehow 'remembers' the previously found keywords, even in the following If-Then statements - resulting in the email being saved in all folders.

I have edited the code based on your comments. It now gives

> error 450: Wrong number of arguments.

```vb
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Option Explicit

Sub Application_Startup()
Dim xNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set xNameSpace = Outlook.Application.Session
Set InboxItems = xNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub


Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal objItem As Object)

'Define variables
Dim FSO
Dim xFilePath As String
Dim xFilePathAgro As String
Dim xFilePathGras As String
Dim xFilePathIndustrie As String
Dim xFilePathActief As String
Dim xFilePathOppTech As String
Dim xMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim xRegEx
Dim xFileName As String

'Create directories if not existing
xFilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
xFilePath = xFilePath & "\MyEmails"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FolderExists(xFilePath) = False Then
    FSO.CreateFolder (xFilePath)
End If

xFilePathAgro = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
xFilePathAgro = xFilePath & "\WBSO 13-01A Agro-reststromen"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FolderExists(xFilePathAgro) = False Then
    FSO.CreateFolder (xFilePathAgro)
End If

xFilePathGras = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
xFilePathGras = xFilePath & "\WBSO 13-01B Grassen"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FolderExists(xFilePathGras) = False Then
    FSO.CreateFolder (xFilePathGras)
End If

'Change filenames of emails to save
Set xRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
xRegEx.Global = True
xRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
xRegEx.Pattern = "\||\/|\<|\>|""|:|\*|\\|\?" 'Is vereist om de onderwerptitel op te nemen in bestandsnaam

If objItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set xMailItem = objItem

    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "")
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, ":", "")
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "/", "_")
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "\", "")
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, "<", "")
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, ">", "")
    xFileName = xRegEx.Replace(xMailItem.Subject, ";", "")
    xFileName = Format(xMailItem.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDD hhmm") & " " & xFileName

    'saving emails that contain the searchwords in the right folders
    If InStr(1, xMailItem.Body, "Agro", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Opgeslagen in Agro"
        'xMailItem.SaveAs xFilePathAgro & "\" & xFileName & ".msg"
    End If

    If InStr(1, xMailItem.Body, "Gras", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "opgeslagen in Gras"
        'xMailItem.SaveAs xFilePathGras & "\" & xFileName & ".msg"
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If InStr(1, xMailItem.Body, Agro, vbTextCompare)` - where is `Agro` defined?`  Did you really mean If `InStr(1, xMailItem.Body, "Agro", vbTextCompare)` ?

Comment: The error is the misuse of `On Error Resume Next`. Remove it and fix the errors you see. As well put `Option Explict` at the top of the module.

Comment: I agree with niton but I would have said a little more about `On Error Resume Next`.  A lot of "experts" include this statement incorrectly.  Used like this, it means "Don't bother telling me about any errors because I like obscure failures".

Comment: I think Tim has correctly identified your error.  `Agro` is an unspecified variable.  Because you have not included `Option Explicit`, `Agro` is declared implicitly and initialised to "".  Since a mail item body will always include an empty string, all three Ifs return True.